# compute image contrast

Tags: image-processing

I need to get information about contrast of an image, and I compute its value in this way:

```
contrast=Pmax/Pmin
```

where `Pmax` is the pixel of the image with the highest value, an `Pmin` is the pixel of the image with the lower value.

Is this the correct way, or there is another approach?

Answer (score 2):

There are many approaches to achieve this. For example, check the following work by Pederson et. al.:

Evaluation of contrast measures in relation to observers perceived contrast *Marius Pedersen1, Alessandro Rizzi2, Jon Yngve Hardeberg1 and Gabriele Simone1.*